# Hash partitioning in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, partitioning, database-partitioning

I have a table like this one:

```
CREATE TABLE "TS1" 
       (    
        "ID" VARCHAR2(32 BYTE) NOT NULL, 
        "CID" VARCHAR2(70 BYTE) NOT NULL, 
        "PID" VARCHAR2(21 BYTE) NOT NULL, 
        "LASTUSAGE" TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL, 
        "CREATIONTIME" TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL, 
        "COSTCENTER" NUMBER NOT NULL
       );

ALTER TABLE "TS1" ADD CONSTRAINT "TS1_PRIMARY" PRIMARY KEY ("ID", "CID", "PID");
```

I tried to find a good way to partition the table considering:

- I have no query that use creationTime in where clause ( So range partition maybe is not the best solution on this field)
- LastUsage is updated very often (so range partition maybe is not the best solution on this field)
- Most of the queries uses ID, CID, PID in where clause

So standing this, a good option should be HASH PARTITION on ID,CID,PID.

```
CREATE TABLE "TS1" 
       (    
        "ID" VARCHAR2(32 BYTE) NOT NULL, 
        "CID" VARCHAR2(70 BYTE) NOT NULL, 
        "PID" VARCHAR2(21 BYTE) NOT NULL, 
        "LASTUSAGE" TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL, 
        "CREATIONTIME" TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL, 
        "COSTCENTER" NUMBER NOT NULL
       )       
PARTITION BY HASH ("ID", CID, PID)
PARTITIONS N;  --N = number of partitions


ALTER TABLE "TS1" ADD CONSTRAINT "TS1_PRIMARY" PRIMARY KEY ("ID", "CID", "PID");
```

Is it a problem if I'm partitioning by hash using the primary key as parameter?
Let's suppose to have lot of records in table TS1 (millions) I will receive some perfomance benefits from this partitioning?

Comment: So a unique index on ID, CID, PID isn't working well?  Not sure the reason/need for hash partitioning for this one table.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? I mean, why do you *insist* on partitioning the table?

Comment: I would like to improve performance.

Comment: What performance problem are you trying to solve? You would be better advised to ask this as a `[performance]` question: provide us with details of data volumes, distribution and skew; examples of queries which run slow together with their explain plans; structure of any existing indexes.

Comment: I would like to have better performance in matter of time for query, considering that most of the queries uses ID, CID, PID in where clause . So the original question was: Could be help to partition the table using hash partition  of ("ID", "CID", "PID")? Or I will have only benefits in term of availability, as you describe below?

At the moment I have only unique index on id, cid, pid (the one of primary key). If I partition for hash ("id", "cid", "pid") can be a good idea use a local unique index on the same columns of the primary key instead the global one of the PK?

Comment: I'm running out of ways to say "no".

Comment: I have expanded my answer with a fourth potential benefits of (hash) Partitioning. Your question implies that the performance issue you're trying to solve is reads (select) rather than writes (other DML). But it rounds out the answer. Again, I say,, you should edit your question to provide more details of the actual problem you need to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Most of the queries uses ID, CID, PID in where clause"

This means most queries are single row lookups on the primary key, so there is no way partition elimination can make things faster. All it might do is make those few queries which don't use the key **slower** (because say reads using an index range scan might not be as performative).

There are three reasons to implement Partitioning. They are:

- **data management**. We can load data into a single partition using partition exchange, or zap data using drop or truncate partition with no impact on the rest of the table.
- **availability**. We can have a separate tablespace for each partition which localises the impact of datafile corruption or similar.
- **performance**. Queries which work with the grain of the partitioning key may benefit from partition pruning. Queries which might benefit are those which will execute a range scan; if we load a million rows into a table each day and we generally want to retrieve records for a given day we would get a lot of benefit from partitioning by day.
- **concurrent DML**. If our application has a large number of users inserting, changing and deleting records we may have e.g. waits for ITL slots or latch contention, some times known. [hot blocks](https://logicalread.com/oracle-hot-blocks-cause-contention-mc01/#.WmhChJOFiRs). Hash partitioning can help here, by distributing inserts and hence all other activity across the whole table.

Partitioning by a hash of `("ID", CID, PID)` won't help you with performance, if the usage profile is as you describe. Nor will it give you any data management advantage. It seems unlikely you're interested in the availability benefits (because millions of rows seems too small a number to worry about).

So that leaves concurrent DML. If the performance problem you are trying to solve is writing rather than reading and the pattern of concurrent activity aligns with some aspect of the primary key (say most DML is for the newest rows) then perhaps hash partitioning will alleviate the latch contention. 
If that sounds like your situation you should test Partitioning in an environment with Production-like volumes of data and Production levels of activity. (Not always easy to do.)

Otherwise Partitioning seems like a solution in search of a problem.

Comment: Partition pruning works also on Hash partition but is limited to equality predicates. Considering this, partitioning by hash ("ID", "CID", "PID"), also if ("ID", "CID", "PID") is the primary key, it doesn't produce any performance benefit?

Comment: If his query always passes in those three fields ("ID", "CID", "PID")  in a query, why wouldn't partitioning help? I think it would. Granted, he doesn't need to with only a few million rows, an index should suffice. But, if the table is going to grow and grow, partition pruning would increase performance as long as the three fields are always in the where clause thus invoking partition pruning... what am I missing?

Comment: If all three PK columns are in the `where` clause then an index will take you directly to the row. I can't see how that would become any more efficient in a partitioned table. I suppose if you want all rows for a specified `ID` then hash partitioning might help, if that's a query the OP ever needs.

Comment: Would hash Partitioning help in that case? Surely RANGE or LIST would be better?

Comment: Hash partitioning was the first thought I had (because the OP mentioned it), but you are right. I shouldn't have mentioned a partitioning type. Read that as _"partitioning might help"_.

Answer (score 0):

My original wrong answer:

*It does not make sense to partition by the primary key because every partition will hold a single row. There is overhead associated with partitioning so you want to keep the number of partitions to a reasonable number like under 1000.*

I think I was thinking of list partitions with your primary key values as the list values. See the comments below.

Comment: The OP is proposing to partition by a **hash** of the primary key. That will split the data across as many partitions as they specify in the `PARTITIONS` clause.

Comment: Yes. I was probably thinking of list partitioning or just in too much of a hurry. Haven't really used hash partitions. Mostly list and range or combination of the two. Not sure how hash partitions would affect performance if you scan a range of data that crosses partitions. Can't really use them for maintenance in terms of removing old data. Anyway, my comment was incorrect. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about creating local indexes on  ID, CID, PID and hash partition on same column. Will there not be benefit of index scan rather scanning index for complete table it has to scan of individual partition